# Узнать значение в двумерном массиве, зная "соседние" значение

Tags: jquery, массивы, javascript

Здравствуйте, есть некий массив:

```
[
{"name":"Меч","id_b":"111","id":"4"},
{"name":"Яйцо","id_b":"112","id":"5"},
{"name":"Красный ключ","id_b":"113","id":"6"}
]
```

Как, зная `'id_b'`, узнать `'id'` или `'name'`?
Был вариант использовать так называемый ассоциативный массив, но тогда это получается не массив, а объект — с ним неудобно работать, так как не работает `.length`.

Comment: 1. Либо просто перебирать массив, пока не найдете нужный `id_b`.
 2. Либо поддерживать дополнительно к массиву индекс в виде ассоциативного массива с ключом по `id_b`.

Comment: > так как не работает .length

Это кто вам сказал такое? [Посмотрите][1].

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/2tr0hj46/

Comment: @deonis, у меня не работает: http://jsfiddle.net/hrdL0u40/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение http://jsfiddle.net/2tr0hj46/3/

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="need_id" value="112"> - Введите id_b
<a href="#" id="button">Нажми что бы найти</a>
```

JS

```
var arr = [
    {"name":"Меч","id_b":"111","id":"4"},
    {"name":"Яйцо","id_b":"112","id":"5"},
    {"name":"Красный ключ","id_b":"113","id":"6"}
];

function doSomething(){
    arr.forEach(function(element, index){
        if (element.id_b == document.getElementById('need_id').value)
            alert('name = '+element.name+', id = '+element.id);
    })
}

document.getElementById('button').onclick = doSomething;
```